# Can SiteNavigationElement in schema.org describe a navigational element which links out to external sites?

Tags: schema.org, html5, microdata

Deployment of some parts of **schema.org** still appear to be at a late experimental stage. After extensive debate, there appears to be a - tentative - method to describe the principal navigation section(s) of a page using microdata:

```
<nav itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
```

So far, so good. We have a **NavigationElement**. And it *belongs to the site*.

But must it provide, explicitly, *navigation to other parts of the same site*?

Or can this navigation section also be one which enables the visitor (or the user-agent) navigate to other parts of the web (ie. external URIs) where the site's parent brand also exists?

**E.g.**

Is this a valid deployment of schema.org vocabulary in microdata:

```
<nav itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<h2>Social Media</h2>
<ul>
<li itemprop="name"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/myFacebook/" itemprop="url" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a href="http://twitter.com/myTwitter" itemprop="url" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/myYouTube/" itemprop="url" target="_blank">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Or can elements highlighted as **SiteNavigationElement** only be those which contain links to other pages on the same site?

Comment: Your example is not correct. `SiteNavigationElement` itself [doesn’t allow to mark up the navigation links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35391904/1591669).

Comment: Hmm. I see. It seems (to me) as if the existing `SiteNavigationElement` is missing a child category (e.g. a hypothetical `SiteNavigationOption`), which `itemprop="name"` and `itemprop="url"` might then legitimately be applied to.

Comment: Yes, that would be needed -- an alternative is to use [`ItemList` with `SiteNavigationElement` as additional type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379111/1591669). But, in my opinion, `SiteNavigationElement` shouldn’t even be used on typical webpages ([I suggested to deprecate it](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1251)).

Comment: I see your consistent position and I am largely in agreement in as far as what `SiteNavigationElement` currently indicates. That said, I also see the utility in being able to describe principal (internal) site navigation links and principal (external) brand navigation links - it seems that this area of schema.org needs a little work at present.